# How to give to a Flutter container the Height equivalent to the child and children inside himself

Tags: flutter

how it is possible to give to the container height the right height of the equivalent of the total children inside this container?
this is my piece of code:

```
child: Container(
          height: ????,<----HERE TO BE IMPLEMENT HEIGHT
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 15,),
              SearchWidget(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 15, 0, 8),
                child: Text('Le offerte del Momento',style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff494949),fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
              ),
```

Comment: Better don't give any value. Remove that line. Or if you you're getting overflow issue then use expanded widget as parent of the column

Comment: Try using in the `Colum` widget: `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`. With this the `Column` will take the less space it needs and you could remove the `Container`. Plus, if you only want to use a widget to define the height or the with it's better to use `SizedBox`.

Answer (score 3):

To get the height of the child use IntrinsicHeight:

```
Container(
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
                        child: Column(
...
```

But as it was said in the comments, unless you need some properties of the Container like a decoration for example, you shouldn't use a Container because it is useless in this case. Just add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to your column so that its size depends on those of children.

Answer (score 0):

If a size factor is non-null then the corresponding dimension of this widget will be the product of the child’s dimension and the size factor. For example if widthFactor is 2.0 then the width of this widget will always be twice its child’s width.

This means that if we set heightFactor to 10, the height of the Center widget will become “10 * height of its child” i.e. “10 * height of Text widget”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).